# Create a child table from an existing field MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am working on trying to create a child table that derives from a set of strings from an field from an existing table. The existing field consists of a set of strings that I would need to parse. See below for an example of the data:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Column                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| ['ffffffff-11111-1111-baaa-xxxx']'                         |
| ['zxyvvv-1234567-abcdefghijk', '1234567-abcdefg-hijklmn']' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The goal would be to take the set of strings from the existing field and create a new table of those strings can join back to the parent table using a foreign key of some type.

```
Parent table
+--------+
| Col_id |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
+--------+

Child Table

+-----------+-------------------------------+
| Col_id    |            Column             |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|         1 | ffffffff-11111-1111-baaa-xxxx |
|         2 | zxyvvv-1234567-abcdefghijk    |
|         2 | 1234567-abcdefg-hijklmn       |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
```

I am not sure the proper approach or "best practices" when handling this kind of scenario. I also assume that I would need to create a foreign key in the child table that references the parent table to perform a join. If there is another post that relates to this topic within Stack Overflow, please provide and mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: That is not a clasical sql task, Can you use some scripting language, or even sql stored procedure can do the trick

Comment: What is the largest number of values that you have in `Column`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there could potentially be a max of 4 values within the Column field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the columns by doing:

```
select substring_index(column, ',', 1) as data
from t
union all
select substring_index(substring_index(column, ',', 2), -1) as data
from t
where column like '%,%'
union all
select substring_index(substring_index(column, ',', 3), -1) as data
from t
where column like '%,%,%'
union all
select substring_index(substring_index(column, ',', 4), -1) as data
from t
where column like '%,%,%,%';
```

Getting the child id is tricker.  You can do this using the original column and some variables:

```
select c.col_id, t.data
from (select column, substring_index(column, ',', 1) as data
      from t
      union all
      select column, substring_index(substring_index(column, ',', 2), -1) as data
      from t
      where column like '%,%'
      union all
      select column, substring_index(substring_index(column, ',', 3), -1) as data
      from t
      where column like '%,%,%'
      union all
      select column, substring_index(substring_index(column, ',', 4), -1) as data
      from t
      where column like '%,%,%,%'
     ) t join
     (select column, (@rn := @rn + 1) as col_id
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) c
     on t.column = c.column;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### MySQL 8 solution with JSON and CTE

Assuming this is your table now:

```
create table old_table(
  data text
);
insert into old_table(data)values
  ("['ffffffff-11111-1111-baaa-xxxx']"),
  ("['zxyvvv-1234567-abcdefghijk', '1234567-abcdefg-hijklmn']");
```

And you want to "transfer" the data into the two new tables:

```
create table parent_table(
  parent_id int primary key
);

create table child_table(
  child_id int auto_increment primary key,
  parent_id int not null,
  data varchar(100),
  foreign key (parent_id) references parent_table(parent_id)
);
```

First create a (temporary) copy of your old table with an AUTO_INCREMENT `id` column:

```
create table tmp_table(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  data json
);
```

While copying from the old table convert the data to JSON:

```
insert into tmp_table(data)
  select replace(data, "'", '"') from old_table;
```

Fill the `parent_table` with the IDs from the `tmp_table`:

```
insert into parent_table(parent_id)
  select id from tmp_table;
```

Now (the main part) fill the `child_table` with the following query:

```
insert into child_table(parent_id, data)
  with recursive seq(i) as ( -- sequence numbers 0 to 999
    select 0
    union all
    select i + 1
    from seq
    where i < 999
  )
  select t.id as parent_id
       , json_unquote(json_extract(t.data, concat('$[', s.i, ']'))) as data
  from tmp_table t
  join seq s on s.i <= json_length(t.data)-1;
```

The `child_table` now contains the following data:

```
child_id    parent_id   data
1           1           ffffffff-11111-1111-baaa-xxxx
2           2           zxyvvv-1234567-abcdefghijk
3           2           1234567-abcdefg-hijklmn
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rvoCDfxUzT6aghqtn979zT/0)

The main idea is to join the `tmp_table` with sequence number from 0 to 999 (generated with a recursive CTE) and use those numbers to extract the corresponding elements from the JSON array.